# Extracting values from multidimensional array where keys are dynamically generated

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
$array1 = Array (
       [a1] => Array  (
               [a_name] => aaaaa
               [a_value] => aaa
             )

       [b1] => Array (
               [b_name] => bbbbb
               [b_value] => bbb
           )
       [c1] => Array (
               [c_name] => ccccc
               [c_value] => ccc
           )

     )
```

Now I want to extract the value of $array1[b1][b_name]. But the thing here is the keys (b1 and b_name) will be generated dynamically. The situation here is I have a multidimensional array and the keys of which i want the value. So how do i get the value.

eg.

```
$array1[b1][b_name]
```

should return

```
bbbbb
```

and

```
$array1[c1]
```

should return

```
array([c_name]=>ccccc
       [c_value]=>ccc
   )
```

and so on...

**EDIT**

Lets keep it this way,
The second array is

```
$array2 = Array (
         [b1] => Array (
               [b_name]=> zzzzz
             )
      )
```

Now Intersecting $array1 and $array2, I want the value of the $array1 ie. bbbbb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
   //you will have $firstkey and $secondkey as index values of $array1
   if (isset($firstkey) && array_key_exists($firstkey, $array1)) {
       if (isset($secondkey) && array_key_exists($secondkey, $array1[$firstkey])) {
           print_r($array1[$firstkey][$secondkey]);
       }
       else {
           print_r($array1[$firstkey]);
           echo "$secondkey does not exist";           
       }
   }
   else {
       echo "$firstkey does not exist";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop to get at both the keys and the values. I am not certain though that it will help you if you only want specific ones and you don't know how to identify them:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}

// From your example of the array inside a1:
// the $key would be: a_name
// the $value would be: aaaaa
```